# Discord.py Welcome/Removed messages in chat

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I am trying to make my bot leave welcome and removed messages using discord.py.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')

@client.event
async def on_member_join(ctx, *, member):
    channel = member.server.get_channel("channel id")
    fmt = 'Welcome to the {1.name} Discord server, {0.mention}'
    await ctx.send_message(channel, fmt.format(member, member.server))

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(ctx, *, member):
    channel = member.server.get_channel("channel id")
    fmt = '{0.mention} has left/been kicked from the server.'
    await ctx.send_message(channel, fmt.format(member, member.server))

client.run('client id')
```

The error

```
File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: on_member_join() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'member'
```

comes up.

I am not sure why it isn't working. I have very little experience with it, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Could anyone tell me what I am missing?

Comment: Remove the `*,` in the function signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   await client.get_channel(idchannel).send(f"{member.name} has joined")

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
   await client.get_channel(idchannel).send(f"{member.name} has left")
```

On event you can't get ctx, because it isn't a command, who must write. It is event

Comment: From that I get the error                                                                                         `File "c:/Tools from Python/f4ll_legion.py", line 15, in on_member_join
    await client.get_channel('id(I have but not posting it on here').send(f"{member.name} has joined")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

Comment: I have `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '.')
bot = discord.Client()` set up. Do I need something else?

Comment: delete `bot = discord.Client()` this is unnessesary and id without '...'

Comment: Give only id or you can in global: under declared library eg. 'welcome = id' and write: 'await client.get_channel(welcome).send(f"...")'

Comment: Im still getting `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send`                                                      The code is                                                                                                                                              `@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   welcome = 'id(again I have)'
   await client.get_channel(welcome).send(f"{member.name} has joined")`

Comment: Do you write correct ID from channel? Take once again

Comment: `await client.get_channel(welcome = 515220931421929484).send(f"{member.name} has joined")`

Comment: `await client.get_channel(515220931421929484).send(f"{member.name} has joined")`

Comment: Oh my goodness, it worked. I can't believe it was as simple as that. Thank you so much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

```python
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
   await client.get_channel(idchannel).send(f"{member.name} has joined")

@client.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
   await client.get_channel(idchannel).send(f"{member.name} has left")
```

also keep in mind that idchannel is int, not string